# How to query over two models to filter out a reference to a model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

Suppose I have two models.

```
class Applicant(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    applicationStatus = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="Pending")
```

and

```
class VolInterview(models.Model):
    applicant = models.OneToOneField('Applicant')
    reasonForRejection = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="N/A")
```

Now I want to find only those applicants that has not been referred by any VolInterivew instance. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Applicant.objects.filter(volinterview__isnull=True)
```

[Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) for `isnull`.